# What kind of Hölder inequality is used in the following two estimates

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, holder-inequality

Let $p \in (1,\infty)$ and $q$ the corresponding Hölder conjugate  $T: \ell^{p} \to \ell^{p}$ where $(Tx)_{j}=\sum\limits_{k \in \mathbb N}c_{j,k}x_{k}$ and $a:=\sup\limits_{k \in \mathbb N}\sum\limits_{j \in \mathbb N}\vert c_{j,k}\vert<\infty$ and $b:=\sup\limits_{j \in \mathbb N}\sum\limits_{k \in \mathbb N}\vert c_{j,k}\vert<\infty$

Show that $\vert \vert T \vert \vert\leq a^{\frac{1}{p}}b^{\frac{1}{q}}$

> Hint:
>
> $\vert \vert T \vert \vert =\sup\limits_{0\neq y \in \ell^{q},0\neq x
>  \in \ell^{p}}\frac{\vert\langle y, Tx\rangle\vert}{\vert\vert
>  y\vert\vert_{q}\vert\vert x\vert\vert_{p}}$ for every bounded operator
>   $T: \ell^{p} \to \ell^{p}$

I have gotten to the following point, using the above hint:

$\vert\langle y, Tx\rangle\vert\leq \vert \sum\limits_{n \in \mathbb N}y_{n}(Tx)_{n}\vert=\vert\sum\limits_{n \in \mathbb N}y_{n}\sum\limits_{k \in \mathbb N}c_{n,k}x_{k}\vert\leq\sum\limits_{n \in \mathbb N}\vert y_{n}\vert\sum\limits_{k \in \mathbb N}\vert c_{n,k}x_{k}\vert=\sum\limits_{n \in \mathbb N}\vert y_{n}\vert \sum\limits_{k \in \mathbb N}\vert c_{n,k}\vert^{\frac{1}{p}}\vert c_{n,k}\vert^{\frac{1}{q}}\vert x_{k}\vert=\sum\limits_{n \in \mathbb N}\vert y_{n}\vert \sum\limits_{k \in \mathbb N}\vert c_{n,k}\vert^{\frac{1}{p}}\vert x_{k}\vert\vert c_{n,k}\vert^{\frac{1}{q}}\leq \sum\limits_{n \in \mathbb N}\vert y_{n}\vert(\sum\limits_{k\in \mathbb N}(\vert c_{n,k}\vert^{\frac{1}{p}}\vert x_{k}\vert)^{p})^{\frac{1}{p}}(\sum\limits_{k \in \mathbb N}\vert c_{n,k}\vert)^{\frac{1}{q}}\leq b^{\frac{1}{q}}\sum\limits_{n \in \mathbb N}\vert y_{n}\vert(\sum\limits_{k\in \mathbb N}(\vert c_{n,k}\vert^{\frac{1}{p}}\vert x_{k}\vert)^{p})^{\frac{1}{p}}$

I get to this point, but then in the solutions (with the justification Tonelli and Hölder), it continues:

$b^{\frac{1}{q}}\sum\limits_{n \in \mathbb N}\vert y_{n}\vert(\sum\limits_{k\in \mathbb N}(\vert c_{n,k}\vert^{\frac{1}{p}}\vert x_{k}\vert)^{p})^{\frac{1}{p}}\leq b^{\frac{1}{q}} \vert \vert y\vert \vert_{q}(\sum\limits_{n \in \mathbb N}\sum\limits_{k \in \mathbb N}\vert c_{j,k}\vert \vert x_{k}\vert^{p})^{\frac{1}{p}}\leq b^{\frac{1}{q}}\vert \vert y\vert \vert_{q}a^{\frac{1}{p}}\vert\vert x\vert\vert_{p}$

I do not understand the last two inequalities. Essentially, how do I get, using Hölder and Tonelli:

$\sum\limits_{n \in \mathbb N}\vert y_{n}\vert(\sum\limits_{k\in \mathbb N}(\vert c_{n,k}\vert^{\frac{1}{p}}\vert x_{k}\vert)^{p})^{\frac{1}{p}}\leq \vert \vert y\vert \vert_{q}(\sum\limits_{n \in \mathbb N}\sum\limits_{k \in \mathbb N}\vert c_{j,k}\vert \vert x_{k}\vert^{p})^{\frac{1}{p}}\leq \vert \vert y\vert \vert_{q}a^{\frac{1}{p}}\vert\vert x\vert\vert_{p}$

Comment: The equation in the box contains some $>$ symbols that don't seem to belong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little late, but in case you still needed an answer:

Let $z_n = \sum_{k \in \mathbb{N}}|c_{n,k}||x_k|^p$.  Then the leftmost term in your last line is $\sum_{n}|y_n||z_n|^{\frac{1}{p}}$.  Applying Hölder immediately, we get: \begin{align*}
\sum_{n}|y_n|(|z_n|^{\frac{1}{p}}) &\le \|y\|_q \|\{|z_n|^{\frac{1}{p}}\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\|_p = \|y\|_q (\sum_{n} |z_n|^{\frac{1}{p}p})^\frac{1}{p}\\
&\le \|y\|_q (\sum_{n} |z_n|)^\frac{1}{p} = \|y\|_q (\sum_n \sum_k|c_{n,k}||x_k|^p)^\frac{1}{p}.
\end{align*}

So the first inequality is just Hölder.  For the second inequality, we reverse the order of summation using Tonelli to get:

$$\|y\|_q (\sum_n \sum_k|c_{n,k}||x_k|^p)^\frac{1}{p} = \|y\|_q (\sum_k (\sum_n|c_{n,k}|)|x_k|^p)^\frac{1}{p} \le \|y\|_q (\sum_k a|x_k|^p)^\frac{1}{p} = a^\frac{1}{p}\|y\|_q\|x\|_p.$$